# phoneGap inApp Browser Issue

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm having some issues about the phoneGap inApp Browser even though I upgrade it to 2.3.0 version.

Right now, our mobile App basically just direct the user to our mobile site(in other word, the pages are not in the app itself).

In the mobile site, i used something like window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');

Whenever user clicks on it, it works fine and opens another window when user using a browser to visit our mobile site.

But when user is using the app, it doesn't work any more, it just loads the page in the same window.

I just put the window.open(....) clause in the index.html in my app, it works fine and it does open another window. But it breaks when visiting our page even though for the same window.open(...) clause.

anybody help me out? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this `window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');` works but `window.open(url, '_self', 'location=yes');` does not work?

have you added     `<access origin=".*"/>` to your config.xml ?

Comment: um, nvm, I use objective c to force to open the browser if necessary. Thanks for answering though